# What could I use instead of the GNOME panel applet "Character Palette" in unity

Tags: unity, software-recommendation, indicator, special-characters

As there is nothing like GNOME panel applets in Unity, I would like to ask about some possibility to supercede the "Character Palette", a function that I used a lot for comfortable embedding of special chars.

Answer (score 3):

It's very quick to load the "Character Map" (installed by default).

In the first screenshot I am loading it from the dash (click on the Ubuntu button in the top left, or press <kbd>Super</kbd>). For even quicker access you could add it to your Launcher on the left as seen in the second screenshot.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, but it is incomparably more clumpsy, as:

1) The Character Map minimises after every clicking in a window of any other programme, so as to paste the char. When you need to enter more different characters subsequently, you have to display the minimised Map window every time.

2) You have to search the chars every time, what can take even one minute for each of them. In the palette I could define a set of frequent signs, that were disponably immediately and always (for instance I had there „“–‚—‘†•’«»[−·×]→…ßſ).

Comment: you could right click on the window and select 'Always on top' .

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to you question, but an alternative suggestion...

I switched to using the compose key after bringing my (US keyboard) laptops to Sweden I found I had to type "å", "ö" and "ä" a lot, and even using the character applet was too slow.

There is a tutorial to enable the compose key here:

[How to Enable Non-ASCII characters on Linux](http://lifehacker.com/5690522/how-to-enable-non+ascii-characters-on-linux)

And a list of the default shortcuts here:

[Linux Compose Key Sequences](http://www.hermit.org/Linux/ComposeKeys.html)

Comment: I used to use the Character Palette to type French and German accents, but this is much better/faster! And the codes are very easy to remember.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1335347/1226617) to find out how you can make it look like Gnome top panel is a part of Unity top panel. The answer also describes how you can add Character Palette into Gnome top panel. This way, you can achieve the same functionality in Unity.