# How do I use the old clock applet?

Tags: 11.04, clock, indicator

The Natty indicator-datetime widget is a HUGE downgrade. It doesn't show a visual indication of time-of-day on the alternate timezones; it doesn't show my upcoming appointments; and it requires me to enter my password just to switch timezones (!!!).

How do I go back to the mature, feature-full date/time/calendar applet I had in Maverick?

Answer (score 2):

Since the old clock applet is not an indicator, but rather a Gnome applet, you will only be able to use it in the classic Gnome 2 session. There is no possible way for it to work in Unity.

If you're using Gnome, just remove the indicator-datetime package:

```
sudo apt-get purge indicator-datetime
```

and right click the panel to add the old applet.

Answer (score 2):

You can [run the gnome-panel in unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39069/how-do-i-use-the-gnome-panel-in-unity/40027#40027) to use the old clock applet .

Comment: Great idea! I never knew that was possible.