# How to add dockbarx (gnome) panel applet to unity panel?

Tags: 11.04, unity, applet, dockbarx

just would like to know if that would be possible because i get used to it in gnome, but would like to use unity, not gnome because unity is more stable on my thinkpad x220.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of DocBarX supports both gnome-panel and AWN ([see this article](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/dockbarx-applet-043-released-with.html)).

Thus if you install AWN together with the latest DocBarX from the PPA then this should work very nicely with the Unity Interface.

An alternative would be to add the [Gnome Panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39069/how-do-i-use-the-gnome-panel-in-unity) to the Unity Interface and add DocBarX as usual to the Gnome Panel.

Comment: Hi, i use in gnome docbarx applet as notifier for opened windows/apps. Anyway to have it in unity panel? E.g. gnome-gmail-notifier works just fine in unity panel.

Comment: Vic - if you install the gnome-panel as per that link, then all gnome applets and notifiers will work - they will be displayed on the gnome-panel.  If you want the notifier on the unity panel, then you will have to experiment with whitelisting docbarx

Comment: Thanks-sorry for not replying to the whole reply. I don´t want to use gnome-panel (tried-didn´t like it) just because of one applet which would i like to have always visible. Could you suggest how to/what is whitelisting? Thanks

Comment: I tried to add to whitelist dockbar/dbx/dbx applet-but nothing. Actually-i don´t know what name of this application should be there for applet? Anyone knows?

Comment: well, i tried all names-but i think that notifications areas (what docbarx) is not supported by unity. More here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1759128

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Dockbarx in Unity itself, because Dockbarx is neither a notification area application nor an application indicator. It is essentially a dock or taskbar, and is to be used either alone, in the GNOME-Panel (GNOME2 only currently) or AWN.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add those types of applets to the Unity panel. However, as others have pointed out, you can install Gnome Panel and run it at the bottom of your screen, which will give you a similar layout as we've had before, except you also get the new niceties from Unity. You will get a conflict with Alt+f2 since Gnome Panel provides its own dialog for that, but I think it should be easy to get used to.

However, there is a large problem with Gnome Panel; it's been deprecated. From 11.10 and onwards, it will no longer be available. Luckily, the XFCE project provides another Panel which works similarly to Gnome Panel. (It's much better in my opinion) and it's actively developed, so it'll be available in the future. Xfce4-panel also supports Gnome Panel applets if you also install xfce4-xfapplet-plugin. (You'll add the XFApplet plugin to the panel).

I think I would recommend that you at least investigate this if you're going to use Gnome panel applets with Unity.