# Why doesn't indicator-cpufreq show up in panel?

Tags: 12.04, unity, panel, cpufreq

I'm using 12.04 and I want to add "indicator-cpufreq" to my panel. It's installed and I try to launch it manually through Alt+F2. It just doesn't show up. Does anyone know why?

Comment: As posted by green7 in the accepted answer, this is a [reported bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-cpufreq/+bug/949240), so it's off topic.

Comment: look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/39069/how-do-i-use-the-gnome-panel-in-unity) for a workaround!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug and has already been reported at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-cpufreq/+bug/949240.

According to the comments on the page, the indicator-cpufreq applet works fine in Ubuntu Gnome Classic running under 12.04 but will doesn't work on Unity.

Comment: Good information, thank you! Guess I just have to wait then.

Answer (score 0):

@ green7 is right, that is a bug. And the bug is same thing wrong with the icon theme, so the  indicator doesn't appear. You can try too switch some other icon theme. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-cpufreq/+bug/949240 #5 floor.