# What types of taskbar are available for Ubuntu?

Tags: desktop-environments, window-manager, taskbar

I want to know what types of taskbar exist for Ubuntu

I know TINT2 but are there any others?

[Blog post in Portuguese on this topic](http://www.ubuntudicas.com.br/blog/2011/10/adicione-uma-barra-de-tafefas-no-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like Docky for many things, though not a true taskbar. More like a HUD.

Answer (score 6):

Lighter weight: (not as customizable/can't add as many applets)

- [pypanel](http://pypanel.sourceforge.net/) (this one might be the most comparable to tint2)
- [fbpanel](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/fbpanel.1.html) ([Ubuntu Manpage](http://aanatoly.github.io/fbpanel/) )
- [lxpanel](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/lxpanel.1.html) (this seems to be specifically for LXDE, not sure if you can use with other desktop envrionments)

Options similar to Docky:

- [Dash To Dock](https://micheleg.github.io/dash-to-dock/)
- [Plank](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/01/how-to-add-a-dock-to-ubuntu-desktop-plank)
- [Dash to Panel](https://www.fossmint.com/dash-to-panel-a-cool-icon-taskbar-for-the-gnome-shell/)
- [Cairo Dock](http://glx-dock.org/)

There's also

- [xfce4-panel](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/xfce) (Which I now use)

Finally, some options are less popular:

- [Avant Window Navigator](https://launchpad.net/awn/) (apparently not in active development--[last updated 3 years ago](https://github.com/p12tic/awn))
- [True Launch Bar](http://www.truelaunchbar.com/)

Edit:

Another option is [gnome-panel](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gnome-panel), which includes a bottom taskbar that lists running applications. In the link, you can see it's available for 14.04 and [this post details how to use it with 11.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39069/how-do-i-use-the-gnome-panel-in-unity?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). I have Ubuntu 16.04 and up until a week ago, I was using a Unity desktop with gnome-panel, which I had added to my Startup Applications. I stopped using Unity about a week ago because of frequent freezes and overall sluggishness. I haven't had time to troubleshoot the setup, so I don't know for sure whether gnome-panel was part of the problem, but still, I wouldn't necessarily recommend adding gnome-panel to a non-gnome environment.

Also I noticed that occasionally gnome-panel interfered with the Application menus of programs that are running (the top panel would load on top of of the application menu). That can be easily fixed by pressing the Super button to call up the launcher then pressing it again to close the launcher. There is a way to permanently remove the gnome top panel, but it takes some fiddling that I didn't want to bother with at the time, since it wasn't a persistent problem.